# How do I check if the number of lines in a set of files is not equal to a certain number? (Bash)

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I want to detect which one of my files is corrupt, and by corrupt it means that the file does not have 102 lines in it. I want the for loop that I'm writing to output a error message giving me the file name of the corrupt files. I have files named ethane1.log ethane2.log ethane3.log ... ethane10201.log .

`for j in {1..10201}
do
if [ ! (grep 'C 2- C 5' ethane$j.log | cut -c 22- | tail -n +2 | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'; done | wc -l) == 102]
then echo "Ethane$j.log is corrupt."
fi
done`

When the file is not corrupt, the input:

```
grep 'C 2- C 5' ethane$j.log | cut -c 22- | tail -n +2 | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'; done | wc -l
```

returns:

```
102
```

Or else it is another number.

Only thing is, I'm not sure the syntax for the if construct (How to create a variable from the 102 output of wc -l, and then how to check if it is equal to or not equal to 102.)

A sample output would be:

```
Ethane100.log is corrupt.
Ethane2010.log is corrupt.
Ethane10201.log is corrupt.
```

Comment: You're missing the `$` for the command substitution: `[ ! $(grep ...) = 102 ]`.

Answer (score 3):

To count lines, use `wc -l`:

```
wc -l ethane*.log | grep -v '^ *102 ' | head -n-1
```

- `grep -v` removes matching lines
- `^` matches the start of a line
- `space*` matches any number of spaces (0 or more)
- `head` removes some trailing lines
- `-n-1` removes the last line (the `total`)

Comment: I understand this, but how do I compare the number of lines to 102? I want the loop to tell me which files do NOT have 102 lines.

Comment: @DanielLuci The `grep -v` removes files with 102 lines from the list.

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo Who is that comment aimed at?

Comment: It was supposed to help @DanielLuci to learn how to compare numbers in bash. I will remove it as it helps no one.

Answer (score 1):

Using gawk

```
awk 'ENDFILE{if(NR!=102)print NR,FILENAME}' ethane*.log
```

At the end of each file, checks the number of lines isn't 102 and prints the number of lines and the filename.